# Deserialize JSON to C# collection

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize/deserialize my C# object to/from JSON.
My C# object has a property of following type:

```
List<BaseClass> objects { get; set; }
```

This collection holds different child objects (e.g. - ChildClass1, ChildClass2).

Serializing to JSON works fine but while deserializing it creates objects of BaseClass in collection (which is obvious :)).

Is there a way I can create concrete child objects while deserializing? 
I tried creating a custom converter by implementing `CustomCreationConverter<BaseClass>`. But the problem is overridden Create method gives me just the type and based on that I cannot decide which object to return (ChildClass1 or ChildClass2)

My JSON string has a Type property by which I can identify the child object to create.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TypeNameHandling` option:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, settings );
```

The TypeNameHandling option "Auto" ensures that type names are included in the serialized JSON
for subclasses. But watch out: these names become invalid when the classes or their namespaces are renamed!